# How to search a word in a Hash rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Hi I am working on a Ruby on Rails project with ruby-2.5.0 and rails 5. I have a hash which can be of different format. I have certain words to search in this hash if any of the word exist in the hash return true with  the word. word can be a key or value.

```
Json Format Example:
{
    "data": {

        "Lines": [{
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "Walmart",
                    "Left": 63,
                    "Top": 33,
                    "Height": 72,
                    "Width": 364
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 72,
                "MinTop": 33
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Save",
                        "Left": 70,
                        "Top": 116,
                        "Height": 26,
                        "Width": 68
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "money.",
                        "Left": 148,
                        "Top": 123,
                        "Height": 25,
                        "Width": 108
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Live",
                        "Left": 267,
                        "Top": 118,
                        "Height": 25,
                        "Width": 59
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "better.",
                        "Left": 335,
                        "Top": 117,
                        "Height": 26,
                        "Width": 100
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 26,
                "MinTop": 116
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "srg",
                        "Left": 53,
                        "Top": 176,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 36
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "2006",
                        "Left": 105,
                        "Top": 176,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 49
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "00006167",
                        "Left": 222,
                        "Top": 177,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "03",
                        "Left": 390,
                        "Top": 178,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 23
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "04247",
                        "Left": 480,
                        "Top": 179,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 62
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 176
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "MOTOR",
                        "Left": 53,
                        "Top": 201,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 63
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "OIL",
                        "Left": 132,
                        "Top": 201,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 36
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 201
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "007310200289",
                    "Left": 230,
                    "Top": 202,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 152
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 202
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "SUBTOTAL",
                    "Left": 297,
                    "Top": 227,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 101
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 227
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "21.97",
                    "Left": 474,
                    "Top": 228,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 61
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 228
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "TAX",
                        "Left": 175,
                        "Top": 250,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 36
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "1",
                        "Left": 228,
                        "Top": 251,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 7
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 250
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "7.700",
                    "Left": 283,
                    "Top": 251,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 62
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 251
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "1.69",
                    "Left": 488,
                    "Top": 252,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 47
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 252
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "rorAL",
                    "Left": 337,
                    "Top": 275,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 61
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 275
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "23.66",
                    "Left": 474,
                    "Top": 276,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 61
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 276
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "SHOPPING",
                        "Left": 160,
                        "Top": 299,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 101
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "CARD",
                        "Left": 277,
                        "Top": 299,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 48
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "TEND",
                        "Left": 341,
                        "Top": 300,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 49
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 299
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "23.66",
                    "Left": 474,
                    "Top": 300,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 61
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 300
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "CHANGE",
                        "Left": 269,
                        "Top": 324,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 74
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "DUE",
                        "Left": 359,
                        "Top": 324,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 36
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 324
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "07/21/15",
                    "Left": 61,
                    "Top": 386,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 101
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 386
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "ITEMS",
                        "Left": 173,
                        "Top": 455,
                        "Height": 42,
                        "Width": 120
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "SOLD",
                        "Left": 326,
                        "Top": 456,
                        "Height": 41,
                        "Width": 96
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "I",
                        "Left": 458,
                        "Top": 457,
                        "Height": 40,
                        "Width": 11
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 42,
                "MinTop": 455
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Washington",
                        "Left": 88,
                        "Top": 539,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 129
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "E-Cycles:",
                        "Left": 226,
                        "Top": 539,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 106
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Free",
                        "Left": 341,
                        "Top": 540,
                        "Height": 18,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Recycling",
                        "Left": 400,
                        "Top": 540,
                        "Height": 24,
                        "Width": 107
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 24,
                "MinTop": 539
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "For",
                        "Left": 103,
                        "Top": 568,
                        "Height": 18,
                        "Width": 37
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Computers,",
                        "Left": 148,
                        "Top": 568,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 126
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Monitors,",
                        "Left": 283,
                        "Top": 569,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "and",
                        "Left": 392,
                        "Top": 570,
                        "Height": 18,
                        "Width": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "TV's",
                        "Left": 441,
                        "Top": 570,
                        "Height": 18,
                        "Width": 48
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 23,
                "MinTop": 568
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "www.ecyclewashington.org",
                        "Left": 52,
                        "Top": 597,
                        "Height": 24,
                        "Width": 301
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "1-800-RECYCLE",
                        "Left": 363,
                        "Top": 598,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 185
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 24,
                "MinTop": 597
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Lou",
                        "Left": 49,
                        "Top": 643,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 36
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Prices",
                        "Left": 101,
                        "Top": 643,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 75
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "You",
                        "Left": 192,
                        "Top": 643,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 36
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Can",
                        "Left": 244,
                        "Top": 644,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 35
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Trust.",
                        "Left": 295,
                        "Top": 644,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 72
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Every",
                        "Left": 386,
                        "Top": 644,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 62
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Day.",
                        "Left": 463,
                        "Top": 645,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 47
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 23,
                "MinTop": 643
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "07/21/15",
                    "Left": 145,
                    "Top": 668,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 100
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 668
            }
        ],
        "HasOverlay": true,
        "Message": "Total lines: 22",
        "ParsedText": "Walmart"
    }

}
```

Suppose i have an array of words ["Walmart","Optical","Anker"]. I want to check if any of the word in array is present in the hash then return true. Json format can be different. Please help me how can i search certains words in a hash. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say json format can be different, we need more example of what "different" would look like.

Comment: Basically i am using https://ocr.space which convert images to text or json. so i will upload an image then the json provided by ocr.space i have to check if predefined words exist in the hash. Hash is not static any no. of keys and values can be there, but it always be a valid json. so have to search the word in the hash.

Comment: do we expect the key we're targeting to always be `WordText` ?

Comment: No we can't target the key.

Comment: Do you just need to know if the word is in the data set at all?

Comment: Yes and i also want to know which data is present in the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to find if the data contains any of a list of words?  If so

```
h = #your data set as posted so I won't put it here again

["Walmart","Optical","Anker"].select{|w| h.to_s.include?(w) } # shows which words were found. 


["Walmart","Optical","Anker"].any?{|w| h.to_s.include?(w) } # returns bool
# => true
```

Pretty simple, I was thinking you needed something more complex. In this case convert the data hash to a string and see if the word is included in the string.

UPDATE:

Perhaps this is more idiomatic in Ruby version >= 2.3 you can dig but you still need to know the structure. @mudasobwa what do you recommend if structure is not reliable?

```
def deep_find_words(hash, words_to_match)
  words =
  hash.dig(:data, :Lines).map do |line|
   line.dig(:Words).map do |word|
      word.dig(:WordText)
    end
  end.flatten
  words_to_match.select{|w| words.include? w}
end

deep_find_words(h, ["Walmart","Optical","Anker"])
```

Comment: can you please tell me where should i place this array as this array size can be increase.

Comment: I am working on api so i am writting this logic on controller. can you please guide me where should i place this logic?

Comment: Post a new question with a start of you controller and we can try to help

Comment: Ok Let me post a new question.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient, counter-idiomatic and [biased and opionated] just ugly.

Comment: @mudasobwa I updated my answer but can you suggest something better? Thanks.

Comment: ["Walmart","Optical","Anker"].select{|w| h.to_s.include?(w) } How it will work as a case insensitive?

Comment: @awsmsid to do case insensitive it's easier to just downcase so: `["Walmart","Optical","Anker"].any?{|w| h.to_s.downcase.include?(w.downcase) }`  or `%w[ Walmart Optical Anker].map(&:downcase).any?{|w| h.to_s.downcase.include?(w}`